# Script to permission a user to list of functions.

Tags: sql-server, function

I need to permission a user for all the functions in a SQL database. I need to schedule this as a job on a database that get restored daily.

After a restore, a user needs to get "select" permission on the function. Here is a screenshot of manually doing it.
http://screencast.com/t/H3jw6Odrk

How can script this action for all the functions. Below is the script to get all the functions in that database. Can someone tell me the command to loop through this function and grant "select permissions, please?

Thanks for your time..

```
USE DBNAME;
GO
SELECT name AS function_name
,SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name
,type_desc
FROM sys.objects
WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%'
order by type_desc;
GO
```

Comment: There is a box on the top of your screenshot that says "Script" -- it will generate a script to apply the values you've selected.  Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it might not be best solution, but one way to achieve this is to use a **cursor**. Than just put this code inside your a job that will run after database is restored and your are done. Please note that this code does not actually `GRANT` permission but only prints out `GRANT` statement, you need to verify that it is what you want, than comment out `PRINT` row and un-comment `EXEC` row.

```
DECLARE @function_name NVARCHAR(250);

DECLARE fun_cursor CURSOR 
FOR
    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) + '.' + name
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION%'

OPEN fun_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM fun_cursor
INTO @function_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'GRANT SELECT ON ' + @function_name + ' TO MYUSER' --Used for debugging
        --EXEC sp_executesql N'GRANT SELECT ON @function_name TO MYUSER',@function_name
FETCH NEXT FROM fun_cursor
INTO @function_name
    END

CLOSE fun_cursor;
DEALLOCATE fun_cursor;
```

Note: to whom it may concern: Please don't comment why cursors are bad, instead provide a alternative solution in your own answer.

Comment: Cursors are bad indeed, but there is a reason they are there: you need them sometimes.